# Find longest route through graph with restrictions

Tags: graph-theory

Q.4 from http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2015/zio2015/zio2015-question-paper.pdf

All flights must originate at airport 0 and end at airport 2. The types of flight taken during the sequence must match the pass sequence, except that it it possible to skip the elements that one wishes to.

Find the maximum number of flights that can be taken using
(a) cacbcbbbbaaacba
(b) aaacaabcccbabac
(c) aababccbcacaaca

Please refer to question 4 of the pdf for route details. I couldn't post a picture because of less reputation.

I also am a beginner in graphs so any links to resources for studying further are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea for solving this is to keep track of the best way for each city to use the ScamPass up to a certain letter to reach that city. A fundamental algorithm for graphs that uses a similar principle is [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

I'll do the calculation for the first ScamPass, `cacbcbbbbaaacba`:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
&0&1&2&3&4\\
\hline
&0\\
c&1\\
a&1\\
c&2\\
b&2&&&&3\\
c&3&&&&3\\
b&3&&4&&4\\
b&3&&5&&4\\
b&3&&5&&4\\
b&3&&5&&4\\
a&3&5&5&6&6\\
a&6&7&6&6&6\\
a&8&7&8&8&7\\
c&9&9&8&9&9\\
b&10&9&10&10&10\\
a&10&11&10&11&11\\
\end{array}
$$

Since we need to end up at $2$, the best we can do in this case is to use $10$ of the $15$ flights. By also keeping track of the flights used to achieve the optimal intermediate results in each step, we could also determine an optimal sequence of flights.